# Doubt regarding the solution of a definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

While solving the integral $$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{a^2\cos^2x + b^2\sin^2x} dx $$  I found out that it can be solved if we divide the Numerator and Denominator by " $\cos^2 x$ " , which will result in $$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sec^2x }{a^2+ b^2\tan^2x } dx $$ after which I can substitute $t=\tan x$ , therefore $dt = \sec^2x*dx$ .

My doubt is regarding the limits of the integral that needs to be changed after the substitution. If I substitute , $ x=0$ , we get $t=0$ and for $x=\pi$ we get $t=0$.

I am stuck with this step.

Comment: Is $\tan x$ *continuous* on $[0, \pi]$?

Comment: Observe that the integrand is symmetric $f(x)=f(\pi-x)$

Comment: @EricTowers, thanks for the hint.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{f}\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x = 
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\mathrm{f}\left(x + {\pi \over 2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x =
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left[\mathrm{f}\left(x + {\pi \over 2}\right) + \mathrm{f}\left(-x + {\pi \over 2}\right)\right]\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the integral as in the point $\frac{\pi}{2}$